# Font issues while integrating ZSH on Visual Studio Code

Tags: zsh, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to integrate zsh on my VSC setup but apparently arrows are not recognized by it.

[image]

My zsh theme is agnoster and I've already tried adding  `"terminal.integrated.fontFamily": "Meslo LG M DZ for Powerline"` with no success. Anyone experienced something like this and can give me a hand? Thanks.

Comment: Which OS are you using and does this issue occurs in other terminals as well?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to specify. I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 and no, other terminals (e.g. sh) are fine. I really think it's a font issue related to the arrows introduced with the agnoster theme but I can't figure out a workaround.

Comment: Have you changed `default shell` to `zsh`?

Comment: Yes I did change it.

Comment: Try this in terminal `sudo fc-cache -vf /usr/share/fonts/`, if this doesn't work give the output of following terminal command: `fc-list | grep -i "Meslo"`

Comment: Nothing changed. The grep doesn't give any results, so it's like Melso font isn't installed. Which is odd because I've already installed powerline fonts  from here 'https://github.com/powerline/fonts'

Comment: Install the font using `sudo apt-get install fonts-powerline` and rebuild the font cache using `sudo fc-cache -vf /usr/share/fonts/` and recheck if it is installed using `fc-list | grep -i "Meslo"`

Comment: Reinstalled `fonts-powerline`, rebuilt the font cache and rechecked if Meslo was present. Sadly still nothing..

Comment: Create a new directory in your home i.e. `~/.fonts` and copy the font you need to it. Clear the font cache again using `sudo fc-cache -vf`.

Comment: I checked which font is used in my Terminal (which is Konsole). It's name is Hack. So I changed VSCode terminal font to "Hack" and it works great

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Following this little guide solved the issue [making-powerline-work-in-visual-studio-code-terminal](https://dev.to/mattstratton/making-powerline-work-in-visual-studio-code-terminal-1m7).

*IMPORTANT*: if you already have a powerline font installed (e.g. it looks fine inside your system terminal), **skip step 1**.

1. Install a patched version of your desired font directly from https://github.com/powerline/fonts. You can **install manually** by downloading the `.ttf` file directly or running the install script `./install.sh` provided. For instance, you can do the following:

   1. Clone the repository:

      ```
      git clone https://github.com/powerline/fonts && cd fonts
      ```
   2. Run `./install.sh` to install them all or install one specific font by going inside its directory and opening the `.ttf` file. For instance, manually installing `DejaVu Sans Mono for Powerline`:

      - `cd DejaVuSansMono`
      - Open `DejaVu Sans Mono for Powerline.ttf`
      - Install the font
2. Add the `terminal.integrated.fontFamily` to your User Settings `settings.json` in VSCode specifying the powerline font to use. For instance, if I want to use `DejaVu Sans Mono for Powerline`:

   ```json
   {
       [...]
       "terminal.integrated.fontFamily": "DejaVu Sans Mono for Powerline",
       [...]   
   }
   ```

Comment: You are using a different font from what you posted in your question.

Comment: Yes but it doesn't mean much to me. I guess that directly installing Meslo from  (https://github.com/powerline/fonts/tree/master/Meslo%20Dotted) would also work. I still don't get why `sudo apt-get install fonts-powerline` would ever fail to achive this task with respect to a manual installation.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 - `sudo apt install fonts-powerline` - worked fine for me.

Answer (score 40):

I had the same exact issue on my Macbook. The problem was that the font I was using in Iterm was not added in the Terminal of VSCode.

[image: Issue]

#### Fix

fix was simple, you have to go to open Iterm -> Preferences -> Profiles -> Text and copy the Font Name[image: iTerm 2]

now head over to VS Code:

- Open settings
- In the search bar, type `Terminal Font`
- Paste the font name in `Terminal > Integrated: Font Family`
  [image: vs code font family]

and that will fix the issue for you!

[image: issue fixed]

Comment: Thank you, I think this may be required on MacOS if you are using iterm as installing fonts and then setting the `terminal.integrated.fontFamily` to the installed font directly doesn't seem to work if you are using a different font in iterm.

Comment: This worked for me while the accepted answer did not... +1

Answer (score 26):

**For me it worked for linux and as well as manjaro (i don't know why others solution weren't working for me).**

Download this font [download font from here](https://github.com/ryanoasis/nerd-fonts/releases/download/v2.0.0/Meslo.zip) , Then create a folder named "Meslo" and extract all the fonts inside it.
Move this folder to `/usr/share/fonts/truetype/`
Run this command:

```
sudo fc-cache -vf /usr/share/fonts/
```

In settings.json of vscode add this line:

```
"terminal.integrated.fontFamily": "MesloLGM Nerd Font"
```

Save and Restart if necessary, it should work. Done.

Comment: Works perfectly for Manjaro Gnome Desktop

Comment: Worked with Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: Worked in Manjaro Plasma Desktop

Answer (score 17):

Finally made it work after going through many blogs and GitHub comments. The below steps works for macOS.

1. Clone the Menlo for powerline font

```
git clone https://github.com/abertsch/Menlo-for-Powerline.git
```

2. Open this folder in finder. Double click on `Menlo for Powerline.ttf` file.
3. Click on `Install Font`
4. Open the `settings.json` file in VSCode and add the below line.

```
"terminal.integrated.fontFamily": "Menlo for Powerline"
```

If you still can't see the fonts in the terminal try restarting VSCode.

You can use the above steps to use any font you want.

Answer (score 10):

If you already have a font installed which is looking fine in your terminal app (for example in iTerm2) and the font is just messed up inside VSCode, you don't have to install any additional fonts. Just add:

```json
{
  ...,
  "terminal.integrated.fontFamily": "YourFontName"
}
```

to your `settings.json`
where `YourFontName` is the name of the font you would like to use. On macOS you can see what fonts you have installed in your font book (search for `font book` in the spotlight <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>) which looks like this:

[image: font book on macOS]

In my case my `settings.json` has the following entry:

```json
{
  ...,
  "terminal.integrated.fontFamily": "MesloLGS NF"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Most of the other answers didn't solve the issue for me in Manjaro Linux (KDE).

I eventually found a solution that made the Powerline glyphs visible in my VS Code zsh terminal:

https://forum.manjaro.org/t/kde-powerline-glyphs-missing-in-vscode-integrated-terminal-only/63742/3

Just set the font to `NotoSansMono Nerd Font`. This font was already installed on my system. I did not need to download any additional fonts.

There are two ways to change the font in VS Code:

1. Change the following line in `settings.json`:

   ```
   "terminal.integrated.fontFamily": "NotoSansMono Nerd Font"
   ```
2. Alternatively, go to **Settings** -> **Features** -> **Terminal** and set **Terminal > Integrated: Font Family** to:

   ```
   NotoSansMono Nerd Font
   ```

You may need to restart VS Code.

Comment: `pamac install powerline-fonts-git` then set vscode terminal font to "MesloLGS NF"

Answer (score 2):

Yey! This works for me... Ubuntu 20.04

Key: Shared fonts think.

https://cloverinks.medium.com/oh-my-zsh-agnoster-theme-not-showing-correct-font-on-vscode-ubuntu-47b5e8dcbada

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with my VS Code, WSL terminal (PowerLevel10K) on Windows 10. It looked exactly like yours. I found that my Terminal>Integrated:Font Family was named incorrectly. I use "DroidSansMono Nerd Font". I had entered it as "Droid Sans Mono Nerd Font".

[image: Incorrect Entry]

That is not the way the font name shows up in programs like Word, Notepad or Photoshop. When I entered as it was shown in notepad,

[image: Used Notepad to Check Font Name]

I closed and reopened my VS Code terminal and everything rendered as expected.

[image: Correct Entry]

So check your installed font name in your operating system's word processing software and see how it is listed. Enter it likewise into Terminal>Integrated:Font Family and your VS Code terminal should render correctly also.

Answer (score 1):

In manjaro, install MesloLGS fonts and change the setting to`"terminal.integrated.fontFamily": "MesloLGS NF"`
in settings.json

while the font path is `~/.fonts`

Answer (score 1):

**Ubuntu 22.04 Solution:**

1. Download and extract fonts:

   ```
   wget https://github.com/ryanoasis/nerd-fonts/releases/download/v2.0.0/Meslo.zip

   sudo unzip Meslo.zip -d /usr/share/fonts/truetype/Meslo
   ```
2. Go to vscode settings: File > Preference > Settings
3. Search : `terminal integrated font`
4. Insert font name : `MesloLGM Nerd Font`

Restart VS Code.

Done !

[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RuURo.png)